# Can you host two CMSes on a single domain?

Tags: kentico

We use Kentico, but have a client who wants the WordPress interface for her blog. Is it possible to:

1. Host two different CMSes on a single domain?
2. Ideally, have the WordPress-hosted blog appear as a subfolder rather than a sub- or separate domain?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the obvious of getting Wordpress to run on IIS which I believe there is a WebPI package for you should be able to do this.

You'd use Kentico as your main application on the website in IIS.  Then create an Application under the Kentico site with your Wordpress site with a virtual URL of /blog.  You'd need to go into the Kentico settings and update the following Settings > URLs and SEO > URL Format > Excluded URLs to "/blog;" so the /blog directory doesn't get processed by Kentico. There may be a few other web.config issues you need to work out but it should work.